# Select2 - adding custom choice in single selection mode (tags:false)

Tags: jquery-select2-4

Is it possible to setup select2 control to accept custom choice
in single selection mode (tags:false) ?

When typing your choice in the search box instead of seeing "No results found",
just see what you typing in and select it by click or pressing enter.

Comment: As you are new, you should read read our [Tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and especially [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Well - I finally found solution myself.
I override original SelectAdapter adding new choice every time you type in
and delete previous temporary choices:

```
$.fn.select2.amd.require(['select2/data/select', 'select2/utils'],
function (SelectAdapter, Utils) {
function XSelectAdapter($element, options) {
    XSelectAdapter.__super__.constructor.call(this, $element, options);
}

Utils.Extend(XSelectAdapter, SelectAdapter);

XSelectAdapter.prototype.query = function (params, callback) {
    var data = [];
    var self = this;
    var $options = this.$element.children();
    var have_exact_match = false;

    $options.each(function () {
        var $option = $(this);
        if (!$option.is('option') && !$option.is('optgroup')) {
            return;
        }
        var option = self.item($option);

        if (option.xtemp === true) {
            $(this).remove(); // previously typed-in choice - delete
            return;
        }
        if (option.term === params.term) {
            have_exact_match = true; // will not choice if have exact match
        }

        var matches = self.matches(params, option);
        if (matches !== null) {
            data.push(matches);
        }
    });

    if (!have_exact_match) {
        self.addOptions(this.option({selected: false, id: params.term, text: params.term, xtemp: true}));
        data.push({selected: false, id: params.term, text: params.term});
    }

    callback({
        results: data
    });
    };

    $('#your_select2').select2({dataAdapter:XSelectAdapter});
});
```